# Raw type , generics, should be parameterized

Tags: java, types, stack

So I'm new to stacks and I have to write a program that solves postfix expressions. I feel like I have the logistics somewhat correct, but I'm getting a warning that says I have a raw type, and my references should be parameterized. I have no idea what that means nor do I know how to solve it. Any ideas?

```
    import java.util.Stack;

    public class Expression<T> {

    int result, num1, num2;
    Stack stack;
    char c;


    public <T> int evaluate(String expression)
    {
    stack = new Stack();

    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); ++i)
        c = expression.charAt(i);

    if (c > '0' && c < '9')
        stack.push(c);
    else
        num1 = Integer.parseInt("" + stack.pop());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt("" + stack.pop());

    switch (c)
    {
    case '+':
        stack.push(num1 + num2);
        break;
    case '-':
        stack.push(num1 - num2);
        break;
    case '*':
        stack.push(num1 * num2);
        break;
    case '/':
        stack.push(num1 / num2);
        break;
    }

    result = Integer.parseInt("" + stack.pop());

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to parameterize the Stack by declaring it as type `Stack<Char>`

Answer (score 1):

A raw type means that the type of data that the stack (in this instance) will hold is unspecified.

Java is considered to be type-safe, so one of its features is to make sure that the proper types are being accepted and stored.  Without specifying the type, the program is more prone to runtime errors.

To remove the warning, just create your stack using `Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();`

(note that a wrapper class `Character` is used, not a primitive `char`. The reason for this is that generic data structures can only hold objects, which primitive types are not.)